# mat-date-range-input of Angular Material does not fire blur event when not selecting the End Date

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular 15` and `Angular Material 14`. The `DatePicker` control code is as below.

```
<mat-form-field class="datepicker-widget" appearance="fill">
<mat-date-range-input 
    [formGroup]="dateForm"
    [rangePicker]="datePicker"
    [min]="min"
    [max]="max">
    <input formControlName="start" matInput matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" formControlName="end" matInput matEndDate placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-date-range-picker #datePicker disabled="false"></mat-date-range-picker></mat-form-field>
```

How can I fire an event when End Date is not selected?

How can we do that?

Comment: Could anyone provide some suggestions...?

Comment: Can you add (dateChange) to startDate?

Comment: I tried. But it throws warning message on click of start date. But I want to throw warning message when the focus is going away from that date control.

Comment: It is a little unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Especially the tile conflicts with what you write in the body.

Comment: I need to show data after selection of Date Range. If the user selects only Start Date, then I cannot display data in the below screen properly. I just want to trigger an event when the focus goes away after the start date is selected.

Comment: okay - you could add (blur)="startBlured = true" (focus)="startBlurred=false" to start and (focus)="endFocused = true" (blur)="endFocused =false" to end and appropriate counteroperations.  show the information when "end == null && startBlurred == true && endFocused == false"

Comment: I am getting `undefined` for both `startBlurred` and `endFocused` variables in `onDateChange` event.

Comment: `focus` and `blur` events are not firing at all here.

Comment: well it would still help if you described what you really really want in the question title and body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on picker closed and show alert if end is empty

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Basic date range picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'date-range-picker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'date-range-picker-overview-example.html',
})
export class DateRangePickerOverviewExample {
  start = new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  end = new FormControl(null, Validators.required)

  pickerClosed = () => {
    if (!this.end.value) {
      alert("Solved this for you")
    }
  }
}



    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" [formControl]="start">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" [formControl]="end">
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #picker (closed)="pickerClosed()"></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wduqe?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.ts